# What are the main types of inflection that can be found in the languages of the world?

Tags: morphology, inflection, distributed-morphology

What are the main types of inflection that can be found in the languages of the world? If you can, define them and give an example for each of them please. Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean by "type" of inflection? Are you asking about form, or about meaning? Do you mean "most common" for "main"?

Comment: Please clarify the question.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because Maybe don't copy *all of* the homework question

Answer (score 1):

For a very high-level overview, you can read chapters 20–29 of the [World Atlas of Linguistic Structures (WALS)](https://wals.info/chapter).

Comment: For a quick classroom handout, see [Inflection and Derivation](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/Inflection.pdf).